# Java Calculator in Netbean "unreported exception ScriptException"

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello this is a replacement post for my calculator error that is written in java, user "Hovercraft Full Of Eels" I do not wish to inconvenience you please discard this post. I will post the code with the error. The problem code is this portion write here. Once again thank you to anyone who is willing to help and hope once it works it will help others starting out. Constructive criticism On the way the code is written is welcome.

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String tarea = textarea.getText();
double display = (double) engine.eval(tarea);
String display2 = String.valueOf(display);
textarea.setText(display2);
```

By the double the error reads........

```
"unreported exception ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
......"
```

When I run the calculator I get these errors.....

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception javax.script.ScriptException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        at my.harrycalc.HarryCalc.equalsActionPerformed(HarryCalc.java:337)
        at my.harrycalc.HarryCalc.access$1300(HarryCalc.java:17)
        at my.harrycalc.HarryCalc$14.actionPerformed(HarryCalc.java:150)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Here is the entire application code....

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package my.harrycalc;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
/**
 *
 * @author William Lane
 */
public class HarryCalc extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form HarryCalc
     */
    public HarryCalc() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        textarea = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        one = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        two = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        three = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        four = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        five = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        nine = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        eight = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        seven = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        six = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        zero = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        times = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        divide = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        equals = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        minus = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        plus = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        about = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jToggleButton1.setText("Close");
        jToggleButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        one.setText("1");
        one.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                oneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        two.setText("2");
        two.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                twoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        three.setText("3");
        three.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                threeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        four.setText("4");
        four.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fourActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        five.setText("5");
        five.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fiveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        nine.setText("9");
        nine.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nineActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        eight.setText("8");
        eight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                eightActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        seven.setText("7");
        seven.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sevenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        six.setText("6");
        six.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sixActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        zero.setText("0");
        zero.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                zeroActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        times.setText("*");
        times.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                timesActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        divide.setText("/");
        divide.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                divideActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        equals.setText("=");
        equals.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                equalsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        equals.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                equalsKeyReleased(evt);
            }
        });

        minus.setText("-");
        minus.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                minusActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        plus.setText("+");
        plus.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                plusActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        about.setText("About");
        about.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                aboutActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                    .addComponent(one, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(two, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(three, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(four, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(five, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(six)
                                    .addComponent(seven)
                                    .addComponent(eight)
                                    .addComponent(nine)
                                    .addComponent(zero))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(plus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(equals, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(divide, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(times, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(minus, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(about)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jToggleButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(textarea))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(textarea, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(one)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(two)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(three)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(four)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(five))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(six)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(seven)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(eight)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(nine)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(zero))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(plus)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(minus)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(times)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(divide)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(equals)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                    .addComponent(about))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jToggleButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        System.exit(0);
    }                                              

    private void aboutActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                     

    private void oneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
     textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "1");       
    }                                   

    private void twoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "2");
    }                                   

    private void threeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "3");
    }                                     

    private void fourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "4");
    }                                    

    private void fiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
               textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "5");
    }                                    

    private void sixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "6");
    }                                   

    private void sevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
               textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "7");
    }                                     

    private void eightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "8");
    }                                     

    private void nineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "9");
    }                                    

    private void zeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "0");
    }                                    

    private void plusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "+");
    }                                    

    private void minusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "-");
    }                                     

    private void timesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "*");
    }                                     

    private void divideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
       textarea.setText(textarea.getText() + "/");
    }                                      

    private void equalsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
               ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String tarea = textarea.getText();




double display = (double) engine.eval(tarea);
String display2 = String.valueOf(display);
textarea.setText(display2);     
    }                                      

    private void equalsKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                  

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HarryCalc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HarryCalc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HarryCalc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HarryCalc.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new HarryCalc().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton about;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton divide;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton eight;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton equals;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton five;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton four;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton minus;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton nine;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton one;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton plus;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton seven;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton six;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textarea;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton three;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton times;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton two;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton zero;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: If you read the first line of your error message its obvious you should surround the 'ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");' with a Try-Catch

Comment: Sharp edge thanks for nothing, I tried a try-catch if you don't want to help then move onto the next post.

Answer (score 1):

[`ScriptEngine::eval`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#eval-java.lang.String-) can throw a [`ScriptException`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptException.html). The line causing you the error is `double display = (double) engine.eval(tarea);`. You need to wrap the line in a `try-catch` and handle the `Exception`.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am not sure how to implement that I don't think the responses on this forum are all that good. I am going to try another.

Comment: @user3444555 Here's a good [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) to help you on your way.